# Android Code Causing Emulator to Close Immediately without Running

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The code below runs however when I go to run the application in an android emulator the application will open then close immediately .I am an android programming beginner thankyou

the code in question is below

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String emailString =email.getText().toString();
            String pwd =password.getText().toString();

            if(!emailString.equals("")&& !pwd.equals("")){
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailString,pwd)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Unrecognised Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else { Toast.makeText  
          (MainActivity.this,"recognised  Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(mAuthListener != null){
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
     }
     }
     }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please share the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize FirebaseAuth.and put .json file in app folder

```
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your loginActivity or MainActivity, whatever. That is define in AndroidManifest file. and check onCreate method again, is there any syntax mistake.

Comment: i do have syntax errors but am unsure of how  to resolve the issue the errors are in this bit of code

Comment: Where it shows error, put cursor on it. It shows the correction of syntax. Or click there and a yellow or red bulb appear on left side of code screen then tell me what it shows.

Comment: the syntax error is right at the bottom of the code and it displays );}}}} as what is needed I have tried this and it still does not work